# How to add a mount on a docker swarm service with the specified owner

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I am looking for an equivalent of mounting a filesystem with the specified owner:

```
 mount -t deviceFileFormat -o gid=ownerGroupID,uid=ownerID /device /mountpoint
```

in Docker Swarm:

```
docker -H tcp://swarm.manager service update my-service \
--mount-add type=bind,source=/opt/efs,target=/efs # how to specify /efs owner user
```

Comment: If I understand the [docker code](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/37302bbb3f4889e9de2a95d5ea018acdab9e4447/vendor/src/github.com/docker/engine-api/types/mount/mount.go) correctly it cannot be done?

Comment: https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/2259